# Get latest row from each row in a set (5M+ rows)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables - **sensors** and **readings**. There is a one to many relation from **sensors** to **readings**.

I need to query for all rows from **sensors** and then get the newest (i.e MAX timestamp) data from **readings** for each row. I've tried with:

```
SELECT sensors.*, readings.value, readings.timestamp
FROM sensors
LEFT JOIN readings ON readings.sensor_id = sensors.id
GROUP BY readings.sensor_id
```

The problem is, I have 6 million rows of data and the query is taking nearly two minutes to execute. Is there a more effecient way I can get hold of the last reading/value for each sensor?

Comment: There is. It's by avoiding this query you have and implementing a trigger that will populate another table with the latest reading for a particular sensor (which is trivial to do). Then, what you do is read from this 3rd table which is a simple and fast operation. Why am I suggesting this - I'm assuming you require the latest reading per-sensor and that you need it **often**. If I assumed correctly, please consider the solution I suggested. I'm sure there will be someone who will provide a solution with the two tables you have, which is why I'm making a comment.

Comment: @Mjh 's suggestion may be a good one depending on the frequency the **readings** table is being updated. This is something you may need to consider.

Comment: Other option may be to add indices, but you need to be very careful with this.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The ***readings*** table has between 10 and 100 rows added every minute at this stage. Would a trigger still be the right way to go?

Comment: Every time you add a new record into **readings**, you'd update the table with **latest** reading (you can even store an ID of the latest reading into this materialization table). That way you don't have to go through entire data set in order to find the latest record, you simply query the table using `where sensor_id = 123456` (just an illustration). This is a common technique when you require the latest data which doesn't require too much manipulation and you have such data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd go about the problem:

- it involves a trigger that populates `latest_readings` table
- it involves another table that I named `latest_readings`.

### The table

I made `sensor_id` unique because I assumed you have **one** reading per sensor. This can be categorized by types by adding an additional column.

Reason for unique index: we'll be using MySQL's `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to have all the hard work done for us. If there's a reading for a particular sensor, it gets updated - otherwise, it gets inserted (in one query).

You can also make `sensor_id` a foreign key. I skipped that part.

```
CREATE TABLE latest_readings (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    sensor_id int unsigned not null,
    reading_id int unsigned not null,
    primary key(id),
    unique (sensor_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

### The trigger

Trigger type is **after insert**. I will assume that the table is named **readings** and that it contains `sensor_id` column. Adjust accordingly.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `readings_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `readings` 
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
            INSERT INTO readings 
                (sensor_id, reading_id) 
                VALUES
                (NEW.sensor_id, NEW.id)

                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE reading_id = NEW.id
                ;
        END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### How to query for latest sensor reading

Once more, I assumed what column names were, so adjust accordingly.

```
SELECT
r.reading_value

FROM readings r

INNER JOIN latest_readings latest
ON latest.sensor_id = r.sensor_id

WHERE r.sensor_id = 12345;
```

Disclaimer: this is just an example and it *probably* contains bugs, which means it's not a copy paste solution. If something doesn't work, and it's easy to fix - please do it :)

Comment: Thanks all and to Mjh for the explanation. That's put me on the right track. I'll need to tweak the trigger a little for my use case, but it's working well. Thanks.